# Como hacer para cargar y visualizar una imagen local

Tags: imagen, img

el siguiente inconveniente que tengo es el de justamente no poder cargar y ver una imagen al sitio web desde la carpeta **img**

```
<img src="/img/proyecto.jpg" alt="Proyecto en curso" 
style="float:left;width:600px;height:400px;">
```

Tampoco puedo cargar y visualizar imágenes de fondo

```
<body style="background-image:url('/img/fondo.jpg')"></body>
```

Ni mucho menos banners

```
</style>
<table align="center" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="/img/banner.png" style="width: 100%; height: 130px"/> 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería de antemano.

Comment: ¿La carpeta "img" está en la raiz?

Comment: Abri la consola en Google Chrome (F12) y probablemten veras que te tira algunos errores porque no puede encontrar la imagen. Ahi podrás ver donde la esta buscando y corregir tu direccion.

Comment: Si, la carpeta efectivamente esta en la raíz a continuación C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda-argenpymes\application\img

Comment: Con respecto a la consola, estos son los errores que figuran: jquery.vegas.min.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.vegas.min.js:11   -----     Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):33  (index):33